# FadeOut and Remove into a FOR doesn't work

Tags: jquery, dom, for-loop, fadeout, removechild

```
for(x=0; x < Number; x++){
   $(this).parentsUntil('.formRow').siblings(ContentValveForm).children('div:last-child').remove();     
}
```

That code works ok, but when I try to add a `.fadeOut` effect and then Remove x amount of items just removed the last. Why? pls I need help.

```
for(x=0; x < Number; x++){
   $(this).parentsUntil('.formRow').siblings(ContentValveForm).children('div:last-child').fadeOut(500, function(){$(this).remove();});      
}
```

Comment: it removes the last because you specify `div:last-child` so its only removing the last child or the `div element`

Comment: instead of `Number` change it with another variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your `for()` loop is way over by the time that 500ms timer on your `fadeOut()` is done.

You should also not use a global variable for `x`.  Change it to:

```
for(var x = 0; x < Number; x++) {
```

Try using `.queue()` around the fadeOut/remove so there's nothing being skipped over.

```
$(this).parentsUntil('.formRow')
       .siblings(ContentValveForm)
       .children('div:last-child')
       .queue(function() {
            $(this).fadeOut(500, function(){
                $(this).remove();
            });
        });
```

Comment: Sorry, x is not a global variable. 
It's working now! thank you!